# Is Job launched from CoroutineScope with SupervisorJob also a SupervisorJob?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In the example below. Is childJob a SupervisorJob?

```
val viewModelScope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + SupervisorJob())
val childJob = viewModelScope.launch {/* do something */}
```

or something like that is necessary:

```
val viewModelScope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + SupervisorJob())
val childJob = viewModelScope.launch(SupervisorJob()) {/* do something */}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll let the code do the talking:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
    val scopeSupervisor = SupervisorJob()
    val explicitSupervisor = SupervisorJob()
    val explicitPlainJob = Job()
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + scopeSupervisor)

    scopeSupervisor.printJobClass("scopeSupervisor")
    explicitPlainJob.printJobClass("explicitPlainJob")
    println()
    scope.launch {
        coroutineContext.printJobClass("context 1")
        scopeSupervisor.printChildren("scopeSupervisor")
    }.join()
    scope.launch(explicitSupervisor) {
        coroutineContext.printJobClass("context 2")
        explicitSupervisor.printChildren("explicitSupervisor")
    }.join()
    scope.launch(explicitPlainJob) {
        coroutineContext.printJobClass("context 3")
        explicitPlainJob.printChildren("explicitPlainJob")
    }.join()
}

fun CoroutineContext.printJobClass(msg: String) {
    println("$msg class: ${this[Job]!!.className}")
}

fun Job.printChildren(msg: String) {
    println("$msg children: ${children.map { it.className }.joinToString()}")
}

val Any.className get() = this::class.java.simpleName
```

This prints

```
scopeSupervisor class: SupervisorJobImpl
explicitPlainJob class: JobImpl

context 1 class: StandaloneCoroutine
scopeSupervisor children: StandaloneCoroutine
context 2 class: StandaloneCoroutine
explicitSupervisor children: StandaloneCoroutine
context 3 class: StandaloneCoroutine
explicitPlainJob children: StandaloneCoroutine
```

Interpretation:

Neither the job in the scope nor the explicitly passed-in job becomes the job associated with the coroutine. The coroutine job is always of type `StandaloneCoroutine` and it is the child of the passed-in job.

Note also that it would be wrong to pass in an explicit `SupervisorJob` which is not a child of the scope's job. If you cancel the top-level job in the scope, this won't propagate to the explicit `SupervisorJob` you created.

Answer (score 2):

As I understood the SupervisorJob it will not affect the children in the way of also modifying it to behave like a SupervisorJob, speaking that the children of SupervisorJob are not able to fail the parent job, but those children will fail if a child job of the children will fail. The behavior is not passed through the children of a job.

In my opinion that also does make sense since your default behavior of cancellation etc. should be the same until you change it for one specific coroutine.

To answer your question you need to explicitly state that you want to start a coroutine with the behavior of an SupervisorJob.